# asbio package in R 3.5.3 Error : object 'hcl.colors' is not exported by 'namespace:grDevices' ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'asbio'

Tags: r, package, asbio

What's happen with asbio instalation here in R-3.5.3? Please.

```
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
asbio  1.6-1    1.7             FALSE

installing the source package ‘asbio’

tentando a URL 'https://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib/asbio_1.7.tar.gz'Hi
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1789938 bytes (1.7 MB)
downloaded 1.7 MB

* installing *source* package 'asbio' ...
** package 'asbio' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error : object 'hcl.colors' is not exported by 'namespace:grDevices'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'asbio'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library/asbio'
* restoring previous 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library/asbio'
In R CMD INSTALL

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\rivad\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpchxkNb\downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages(NULL, .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) :
  installation of package ‘asbio’ had non-zero exit status
```

Thank you

Comment: (1) I suggest you submit a new issue to the authors: the package incorrectly depends on `R >= 3.5.0`, but is importing `grDevices::hcl.colors` which did not appear until R-3.6.0. (2) R-3.5.3 is rather old/out-dated, this may not be your only issue when trying to install current versions of packages into a 3+ year release.

Comment: (3) While you're talking with the author(s), the vignette PDFs linked on CRAN's page are rather broken as well, suggesting their build process is not running cleanly.

Comment: (You can find the author's email on the [`asbio` CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/asbio/index.html).)